# python add character to filename

Tags: python

Im trying to add a "." after the last occurrence of a integer starting backwards from ".html"

python

```
import os
import glob
import re
for name in glob.glob('*.html'):
  newname = re.compile('name(.*?)(\d+)')
os.rename(name, newname)
```

change filenames from:

```
1cor12.html
gen1.html
```

to:

```
1cor.12.html
gen.1.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like should do:

```
re.sub('(\d+)(?=\.html)', r'.\1', s)
```

Comment: This also does not work if the digits don't immediately follow the *.html*.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
re.sub(r'(\d+\.html)',r'.\1',r'1cor12.html')
```

Note, this only works if you want numbers *immediately* preceding ".html".  In other words, this will do nothing to "gen1a.html".

If you want to match the latter case ('gen1a.html') you could probably do something like:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+\D*\.html)',r'.\1',r'1cor12.html')
```

Comment: That won't work if the digits don't immediately precede the *.html*.

Comment: the digits always come before .html but did not change "gen1.html" to "gen.1.html"

Comment: @kojiro -- Yeah, I know.  I was assuming the problem was a little easier than stated (hence the "is this what you what?"), but I suppose I'll document that.

Comment: @kojiro -- Fixed so it will work if digits don't immediately precede the *.html*

Comment: @mgilson nicely done. It even matches *1a2b3c.html*, returning *1a2b.3c.html*, which is exactly what OP asked for. Too bad he didn't ask for what he actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
newname = "%s.%s.html" % re.match(r"(.*)(\d+)\.html", oldname).groups()
```